# Redis Session DB Shows Zero 0 Keys for sessions?

Tags: magento-1.9, full-page-cache, redis, cm-redissession

When looking at the Redis Manager in the Back End, it always shows zero (o) keys for the sessions?

[image]

The .var/session is also empty.
Any idea on this?

We are running CE1.9.2.2.

```
<!-- 
<session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>
-->

    <session_save><![CDATA[db]]></session_save>
    <redis_session>
        <host>127.0.0.1</host>
        <port>6379</port>
        <password></password>
        <timeout>2.5</timeout>
        <persistent></persistent>
        <db>1</db>
        <compression_threshold>2048</compression_threshold>
        <compression_lib>gzip</compression_lib>
        <log_level>1</log_level>
        <max_concurrency>6</max_concurrency>
        <break_after_frontend>5</break_after_frontend>
        <break_after_adminhtml>30</break_after_adminhtml>
        <first_lifetime>600</first_lifetime>
        <bot_first_lifetime>60</bot_first_lifetime>
        <bot_lifetime>7200</bot_lifetime>
        <disable_locking>0</disable_locking>
        <min_lifetime>60</min_lifetime>
        <max_lifetime>2592000</max_lifetime>
    </redis_session>

   <cache>
      <backend>Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis</backend>
      <backend_options>
        <server>127.0.0.1</server>
        <port>6379</port>
        <persistent></persistent>
        <database>2</database>
        <password></password>
        <force_standalone>0</force_standalone>
        <connect_retries>1</connect_retries>
        <read_timeout>10</read_timeout>
        <automatic_cleaning_factor>0</automatic_cleaning_factor>
        <compress_data>1</compress_data>
        <compress_tags>1</compress_tags>
        <compress_threshold>20480</compress_threshold>
        <compression_lib>gzip</compression_lib>
        <use_lua>0</use_lua>
      </backend_options>
    </cache>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do you have these files ?

```
app/etc/modules/Cm_RedisSession.xml
app/code/community/Cm/RedisSession
```

is it enabled?

```
 app/etc/modules/Cm_RedisSession.xml

<config>
<modules>
<Cm_RedisSession>
<active>false</active>
<codePool>community</codePool>
</Cm_RedisSession>
</modules>
</config>
```

also use `lzf` for compression

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce18-ee113/using_redis.html#config

> Important: The Cm_RedisSession module in CE 1.8 is disabled by
>   default. Magento disables the module to avoid unnecessary connection
>   tries to Redis when you choose to use file, database, or a different
>   session storage method.
>
> To enable Magento to use Redis, perform the following tasks:
>
> Enable the Cm_RedisSession module.
>  Open
>   magento-install-dir/app/etc/modules/Cm_RedisSession.xml in a text
>   editor.
>  Change the value of  to true.
>  Save your changes to
>   Cm_RedisSession.xml and exit the text editor.
>  Modify
>   magento-install-dir/app/etc/local.xml.
>  For configuration information,
>   see the sample provided with Magento in
>   magento-install-dir/app/etc/local.xml.additional and also see the
>   Readme (session) and Readme (back end).
>  Flush the Magento cache in any
>   of the following ways:
>  If you have access to the file system as the
>   owner of the files in the Magento installation directory, change to
>   that directory and enter rm -rf var/cache.
>  Log in to the Admin Panel
>   as an administrator.
>  Click System > Cache Management, then click Flush
>   Magento Cache at the top of the page.

Comment: app/etc/modules/Cm_RedisSession.xml was set to false after upgrading from 1.9.2.0 to 1.9.2.2. Never thought of that. Thanks for a comprehensive answer, working just perfect now.

Comment: Just a note on the lzf compression, the server is running FreeBSD, and we are unsure that this lzf compression is installed on the server.

Comment: nevermind, you can always install it, in fact it faster than gzip